# Half of the boxplot made in GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics, boxplot

I'm doing a boxplot using the ggplot2 package, however, for some external reason, only half of the boxplot is being made for the "Control" and "Commercial IMD" treatments.

See below that when making the graph using the "boxplot" function, the graph is normally done.

```
mediasCon = tapply(dados$CS, dados$Trat, mean)
boxplot(dados$CS ~ dados$Trat, data = dados, col="gray", 
        xlab = 'Tratamentos', ylab = 'Espermatozoides - Cabeça Solta')
points(1:3, mediasCon, col = 'Red', pch = 16)
```

[image]

However, when making the same graph using the GGPLOT2 function, see that for the first two treatments only half of the graph is being done, why is this occurring?

Plus, how do I add boxplot "tails" using a ggplot2 function?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dados, aes(x=Trat, y=CS)) + geom_boxplot(fill=c("#DEEBF7","#2171B5","#034E7B"),color="black") +
  xlab('Tratamentos') +
  ylab('Espermatozoides - Cabeça Solta') + 
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="black", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=5) + 
                     theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
                     axis.text = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the help file under `?geom_boxplot` you will see:

> The lower and upper hinges correspond to the first and third quartiles (the 25th and 75th percentiles). This differs slightly from the method used by the **boxplot()** function, and may be apparent with small samples. See **boxplot.stats()** for more information on how hinge positions are calculated for **boxplot()**.

In your case, the 4 entries for `IMD Commercial` are `c(0, 1, 1, 1)`, which is certainly a small sample.

One way around this is to calculate where you want the hinges to be and pass that data to `ggplot`, using `stat = "identity"`. This makes the code a bit more complex, but this is often the case when you are trying to modify default behaviour:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  group_by(Trat) %>%
  summarize(median = median(CS), mean = mean(CS),
            upper = quantile(CS, 0.75, type = 2),
            lower = quantile(CS, 0.25, type = 2),
            max = max(CS), min = min(CS)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Trat, y = mean, fill = Trat)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = min, lower = lower, 
                   middle = median, upper = upper, ymax = max),
               stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 21, fill = "red") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#DEEBF7","#2171B5","#034E7B")) +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab('Tratamentos') +
  ylab('Espermatozoides - Cabeça Solta')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you @AllanCameron. But how can I make this change? I'm a layman in ggplot2 and would like to make this graph as follows using the boxplot function

Comment: @BrenoG. I don't understand - I have showed you how to make the same plot in `ggplot` as you made in `boxplot`. If you copy and paste my code you will get the same result. Is this not what you were looking for?

Comment: I would like the graph to look like the "boxplot" function, with only half of the graph appearing. Can this not be corrected?